# Get variables from base64_encode url?

Tags: php

I'm studying a way of encoding or encrypting my url variables, but I don't see how to get them back...

Having this

`_link_=Home&nc=1&plw=950&pmw=0&prw=`

I used to do `$_GET['_link_']`

but when base64_encode the url like

```
base64_encode("_link_=Home&nc=1&plw=950&pmw=0&prw=");

echo base64_decode($string);
```

how do I get my **_*link*_** or my **nc** variables back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like http://www.example.com/?BASE64ENCODEDSTRINGHERE, you can do the following:

```
$query_string = base64_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
parse_str($query_string, $getdata);
```

In this case you will have same data in `$getdata` array as you would normally have in $_GET.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php after base64 decode